# Dock extension causing high gnome-shell CPU usage

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, cpu, cpu-load

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Dell XPS13.

Ever since upgrading to 22.04, I've had trouble with gnome-shell using excessive amounts of CPU (upwards of 80-90%). In order to pinpoint the problem, I tried switching all Extensions off one by one. I only have the built-in extension, so I didn't expect any major troubles, but sure enough, switching off the Ubuntu Dock extension lead to a drop of CPU usage from ~30-40% to single-digit numbers.

Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour and how to fix it?